# Construction of Galois cover of $P^{1}$, Abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, galois-theory, algebraic-groups

I am reading from Topics in Galois Theory by Serre. I have the following Question:

Let us say that $G$ has property $Gal_{T}$ if there is a regular $G$-covering $C\longrightarrow P^{1}$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now there is proposition, which says that.

**Proposition** :Let $A$ be a finite abelian group.
There exists a torus $S$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and an embedding of $A$ in
$S(\mathbb{Q})$, such that the quotient $S^{'} = S/A$ is a permutation torus.(In particular $S^{'}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational variety.)

According to the author the above proposition implies that $A$ has property $Gal_{T}$.

I did not had any previous knowledge about algebraic groups, torus, isogeny,etc. I read the definitions first and then tried to understand how the above proposition implies that abelian groups has property $Gal_{T}$ But still I am not able to understand.

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LS3OBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=permutation+torus&source=bl&ots=mwBL4CxvD_&sig=pAnpdhCV6-aYaFE-QDfd3QGxa84&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirzJ-5v-PPAhVCwlQKHScwB6cQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=permutation%20torus&f=false. Here is the link. Section 4.2, Proposition 4.2.1

Comment: You need to be way more specific about exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: @nesos I don't understand how the proposition stated above implies that Abelian groups have property $Gal_{T}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p : S\rightarrow S/A = S'$ be the quotient map. The fact that $A$ is embedded in $S(\mathbb{Q})$ means that $A$ acts freely on $S$, the action is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence $A = Gal(p)$.

The fact that $S'$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational variety means that it's birational to $\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Q}}$ for some $n$, so there is an open subscheme $U\subset S'$ which is isomorphic to an open subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$. By restricting onto some 1-dimensional subscheme, you obtain a subscheme $V\subset S'$ such that $V$ is isomorphic to some open subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^1$. At this point you can already apply Hilbert Irreducibility to deduce that there is a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point of $V$ with connected fiber (ie, the fiber is a $A$-Galois cover of $\mathbb{Q}$).

But, if you really want to get a $A$-Galois cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$, then let $S_V$ be the preimage of $S$ over $V$, then $S_V\rightarrow V$ is finite etale and Galois with Galois group $A$.

To get a $A$-Galois cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$, simply embed $V$ in $\mathbb{P}^1$, and take the normalization of $\mathbb{P}^1$ inside $S_V$.